# Inconsistency between Func and Action with different amount of constructor parameters?

Tags: c#, action, anonymous-function, func

I am working on a twitch chat bot and in my Command.cs class I came across a weird issue. I have one constructor that takes an `Action<string, User, Channel>` and one that takes a `Func<string, User, Channel, bool>`. The first constructor is supposed to call the second one with a `Func` which calls the `Action` and return true. This was working fine when I was using 7 parameters in both constructors but as soon as I added the 8th one it stopped compiling.

The error I get is CS8030 "Anonymous function converted to a void returning delegate cannot return a value." but before I added the 8th parameter the code was compiling just fine

The only difference between the two snippets is that I added an additional `description` parameter.

before:

```
public class Command
{
    public Command(string name, Action<string, User, Channel> action, bool adminOnly = false, bool modOnly = false, bool ownerOnly = false, bool hasUserCooldown = true, TimeSpan? cooldown = null, bool allowOtherCommands = false)
        : this(name, (m, u, c) => { action(m, u, c); return true; }, adminOnly, modOnly, ownerOnly, hasUserCooldown, cooldown)
    {

    }

    public Command(string name, Func<string, User, Channel, bool> action, bool adminOnly = false, bool modOnly = false, bool ownerOnly = false, bool hasUserCooldown = true, TimeSpan? cooldown = null, bool allowOtherCommands = false)
    {

    }
}

public class User { }
public class Channel { }
```

after:

```
public class Command
{
    public Command(string name, Action<string, User, Channel> action, bool adminOnly = false, bool modOnly = false, bool ownerOnly = false, bool hasUserCooldown = true, TimeSpan? cooldown = null, bool allowOtherCommands = false, string description = null)
        : this(name, (m, u, c) => { action(m, u, c); return true; }, adminOnly, modOnly, ownerOnly, hasUserCooldown, cooldown, description)
    {

    }

    public Command(string name, Func<string, User, Channel, bool> action, bool adminOnly = false, bool modOnly = false, bool ownerOnly = false, bool hasUserCooldown = true, TimeSpan? cooldown = null, bool allowOtherCommands = false, string description = null)
    {

    }
}

public class User { }
public class Channel { }
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: Don't see any difference between your before and after code though.

Comment: @Rahul I added a parameter at the very end of the constructor "string description = null" after allowOtherCommands

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In both versions you forgot to pass the `allowOtherCommands` optional parameter to the second method. While in the first method it's just a logical bug that cannot be caught by the compiler, in the second case the `description` parameter is causing the compiler to map the call to the same constructor which is expecting `Action`, hence the error.

Just pass all the optional parameters and the problem will be resolved:

```
public Command(string name, Action<string, User, Channel> action, 
    bool adminOnly = false, bool modOnly = false, bool ownerOnly = false, bool hasUserCooldown = true, 
    TimeSpan? cooldown = null, bool allowOtherCommands = false, string description = null)
    : this(name, (m, u, c) => { action(m, u, c); return true; }, 
        adminOnly, modOnly, ownerOnly, hasUserCooldown, 
        cooldown, allowOtherCommands, description)
{

}
```